# How to find the offset between two time series that minimizes their euclidean distance?

Tags: time-series, similarity

I'm looking for some methods to compute shape similarity between two curve segments.

I have two time series x1 (purple line) and x2 (red line) and I would like to find the y-offset that minimizes the difference between the two curves (the sum of the square differences), and use this difference as a similarity measure.

How can I find this offset?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you intend to do with the polynomial. In many cases using the sum of the Euclidean distances, like you suggest, is a reasonable approach.

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear (removing the useless information about the polynomial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a relaxing week end, it's easier to see the obvious: it's the average distance between simultaneous points of the data sets.

Comment: ...or equivalently, the difference between the mean values of the two data sets.